# Google Sheets Absolute references in Graphs

Tags: google-sheets, insert

I have a set of Google sheets where various things are computed and I'm looking to make a sheet with some visualizations for the raw metrics.

For instance if I wanted to pull the range 
"Employee Metrics!A1:D11"  for a graph where A1-D1 are the headers, and 2-11 are the first 10 rows of data it wouldn't be a problem; however, since I'm using the Google Sheets API to insert new rows on the "Employee Metrics" sheet (so that my list is in reverse chronological order new -> old) the rows keep getting updated in my graphs.

After 5 days it will be "Employee Metrics!A1:D16" as the data source that's being used.  As more rows are added, more is displayed in a graph only meant to be 10 days.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Unfortunately I can't due to personnel information / confidential information tracking.